# Read Variable from Web.Config

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-config

How can I add and read the value from **web.config** file?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sd_patel/webconfiginaspnet11242005061608am/webconfiginaspnet.aspx

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I would suggest you to don't modify web.config from your, because every time when change, it will restart your application.

However you can read web.config using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`

Comment: Thank You Mr.Muhammed , so what you advice me to do to save a variable in a public place that can be changed without restating the web application ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can store such variables in an encrypted XML file.

Comment: yes, XML file is the better idea. Or you can store it in DB and add in application_start (Global.asax), put it in application variable and use these in application. these variable assign only once in the application and if your application restart, these will assigned again.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Vamyip and Mr.Muhammed for your help

Answer (score 161):

Given the following web.config:

```xml
    <appSettings>
         <add key="ClientId" value="127605460617602"/>
         <add key="RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:49548/Redirect.aspx"/>
    </appSettings>
```

Example usage:

```
using System.Configuration;

string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
string redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"];
```

Comment: +1 nice answer. However one note - you don't need to call `ToString` explicitly, as indexers on `AppSettings` return value of type `string` themselves

Answer (score 16):

If you want the basics, you can access the keys via:

```
string myKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"].ToString();
string imageFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageFolder"].ToString();
```

To access my web config keys I always make a static class in my application. It means I can access them wherever I require and I'm not using the strings all over my application (if it changes in the web config I'd have to go through all the occurrences changing them). Here's a sample:

```
using System.Configuration;

public static class AppSettingsGet
{    
    public static string myKey
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"].ToString(); }
    }

    public static string imageFolder
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageFolder"].ToString(); }
    }

    // I also get my connection string from here
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
       get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the key is contained inside the `<appSettings>` node:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["theKey"];
```

As for "writing" - put simply, **dont.**

The web.config is not designed for that, if you're going to be changing a value constantly, put it in a static helper class.

Answer (score 3):

Ryan Farley has a great post about this in his blog, including all the reasons why not to write back into web.config files: 
[Writing to Your .NET Application's Config File](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/07/13/879.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am siteConfiguration class for calling all my appSetting like this way. I share it if it will help anyone.

add the following code at the "web.config"

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
     <!-- some stuff omitted here -->
   </configSections>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="appKeyString" value="abc" />
      <add key="appKeyInt" value="123" />  
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now you can define a class for getting all your appSetting value. like this

```
using System; 
using System.Configuration;
namespace Configuration
{
   public static class SiteConfigurationReader
   {
      public static String appKeyString  //for string type value
      {
         get
         {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("appKeyString");
         }
      }

      public static Int32 appKeyInt  //to get integer value
      {
         get
         {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("appKeyInt").ToInteger(true);
         }
      }

      // you can also get the app setting by passing the key
      public static Int32 GetAppSettingsInteger(string keyName)
      {
          try
          {
            return Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(keyName));
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Now add the reference of previous class and to access a key call like bellow

```
string appKeyStringVal= SiteConfigurationReader.appKeyString;
int appKeyIntVal= SiteConfigurationReader.appKeyInt;
int appKeyStringByPassingKey = SiteConfigurationReader.GetAppSettingsInteger("appKeyInt");
```