# Where should we store service connection URL for JavaScript calls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf

I'm creating a web site that makes calls to a WCF service that we host. Notice that the URL is hard-code in the JS:

```
    var config = {
        url: 'http://serverName:8000/MmaWebApiService/CreateCassette',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { 'moduleSerialNumbers': 'dataHere' }
    };
```

Where are we supposed to store URLs? I would think the web.config file would be a good spot, but I'm not sure how to access it. [One suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152853/279516) is something like this:

```
<img id="ImgHeader" runat="server" src="<%$ ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ImagePath"] %>" />
```

However, I don't think that will work with my plain ol' HTML page, using AngularJS. I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to store service URLs so I don't have them hard-coded all over my JS. For example, if we deploy to a different server, I don't want to have to find all calls in JS and replace the server name. I must be missing a best practice.

Comment: It all kind of depends. You could use the method you mentioned before. At my company we populate an object in the main layout with various URLs provided by the server. [You can read from Web.config using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854777/read-variable-from-web-config).

Comment: You could just put them in a .js file and include the script in the header.  In a single page app, I've usually stored them in a .json file and loaded it via ajax call when required.

Comment: Mike: I don't think I can use ConfigurationManager in JS. Jesse: Good tip. I may try that. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a javascript task runner like gulp or grunt?  If so, you can go the route of `app.constant(...)` and then have your task runner figure out what to do based on if you ran, for example, `gulp dev` or `gulp prod`

Comment: The fact that this was closed as opinion-based is ridiculous. Someone needs to know how to do something and it gets closed because others may have differing opinions. Frustrating.

Comment: I found a good approach, and I was going to post it as an answer, but now I can't because it's closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the correct URL is determined at deployment time, it's a deployment concern. So I used our deployment tool ([Presto](https://presto.codeplex.com/)) to modify the URL *during* the deployment process. I ended up storing the root URL in index.html:

[image]

Notice that I gave it an ID (connection) so it can be altered later by our deployment app.

Then, in my AngularJS controllers, I use it like this:

```
        var config = {
            url: rootWebApiUrl + '/api/Cassette',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: [$scope.state.subId1, $scope.state.subId2, $scope.state.subId3]
        };
```

I set Presto to modify the URL at deployment time by setting the URL to the name of the server where the Web API is being deployed.

[image]

There is a slight issue with this approach: The index.html has to be able to be XML-parsable in order for the deployment app to modify it. That means I had to alter some lines, like this:

Must be uppercase:

```
<!DOCTYPE html[]>
```

Must close any meta tags (need the closing forward slash):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

ng-view has to have =”” after it:

```
<div ng-view="">
```

I made those changes and the app still runs. So I think I’m good.

Answer (score 2):

Angular lets you define constants in the module setup.

```
angular.module('app').constant(
    ENDPOINT, {
        "URL": 'http://serverName:8000/MmaWebApiService/CreateCassette'
    }
);
```

You now have a constant that can be injected into a controller or service as per usual.

```
angular.application('app').controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
myCtrl.$inject['ENDPOINT'];
function myCtrl(ENDPOINT) {
    var myUrl = ENDPOINT.URL;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if that's a better approach than what Jesse suggested: just put the URLs in a JS file.

Comment: Well, your Angular app won't start if it can't find the module configuration. It will run (albeit poorly) if it can't load an external configuration file.

Comment: What about the deployment story? How do you change URLs based on deploying to QA or prod? Is that a manual step?